# Sparking when touching terminal on valve

Tags: 12v, flyback

In an effort to protect my relay I have added a diode for flyback protection. However when I touch the second terminal with power from the circuit I see a small spark.  The source voltage is 12 volts, I'm using zener diode nte5166a.  The water valve is a 4.8 w 12 volt DC.  I'm including images of the circuit. The question I have is should I worry about this?

[image: overhead image of circuit]

[image]

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Why do you use a zener diode as flyback clamp? With what do you touch which "second" terminal with power from what circuit? What is your power supply? A diode does not protect the relay, it protects the driver stage.

Comment: @Jens So the choice was based on a video I watched. The video indicated the relay board could be damaged by the backflow of electricity coming from the valve shutting off.  I will plead some ignorance here.  The power supply I used for this test circuit is a 12 v 1.5 amp wall wart.  I am touching with a dupont style connector.   I'm using a relay board so it's the relay plus some extra circuitry.

Comment: Ah, I see. You want to protect the relay contact from arcing at load turn off. A good idea, but for this you don't need a zener diode. The NTE5166A is a 200 V zener diode and this is so far away from your 12V supply, that we can consider this as a standard diode here. Typically you connect the diode parallel to the valve with cathode connected in positive supply direction.

Comment: @jens ok so I was concerned that it was not right but was all I had at the time.  So a 12v diode across the valve would address this correctly?

Comment: You can use any standard diode, that can carry 2A peak, the "classic" part in such a situation is 1N4001. There is no special voltage requirement.